# filter array within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array like this

```
  @track arrayvar =   [
      {"key":"Array1","value":["test1","test2","test3"],
      {"key":"Array2","value":["test4"]
    ]
```

suppose i select `test1` , i want to remove it from `arrayvar` array

Below code i am trying it using filter function , but unable to remove the element

```
  handleRemove(eve) {
    console.log(eve.target.name)
    var removeSelected = eve.target.name;
    this.arrayvar = this.arrayvar.filter(
      item => item.value.filter(item3 =>  item3 !== removeSelected)
      );
    }
```

Comment: What's `@track` and is your question related to that, specifically, or just arrays in general?

Comment: You're not saving the result of your inner call to `filter`. Also, there's no reason to use `filter` for the outer array, you aren't removing any entries from it. Instead, use `forEach` or just a `for...of` loop: `for (const item of this.arrayvar) { item.value = item.value.filter(item3 => item3 !== removeSelected); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the result after filtering back to `item.value`:

```js
let arrayvar = [{
    "key": "Array1",
    "value": ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
  },
  {
    "key": "Array2",
    "value": ["test4"]
  }
]
let removeSelected = "test1";
this.arrayvar = arrayvar.filter(item => item.value = item.value.filter(item3 => item3 !== removeSelected));
console.log(arrayvar);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are `n` number of options.

If you want to create a new array from existing one use`Array.map`

```js
const arrayvar = [
  {
    "key": "Array1",
    "value": ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
  },
  {
    "key": "Array2", "value": ["test4"]
  }
]

const selectedValue = "test1";
const output = arrayvar.map((node) => ({
  key: node.key,
  value: node.value.filter((item) => item !== selectedValue)
}))
console.log(output);
```

If you just want to modify the existing array Use `Array.forEach`

```js
const arrayvar = [
  {
    "key": "Array1",
    "value": ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
  },
  {
    "key": "Array2", "value": ["test4"]
  }
]

const selectedValue = "test1";
arrayvar.forEach((node) => {
  node.value = node.value.filter((item) => item !== selectedValue);
})
console.log(arrayvar);
```